# Native code debug is not working in Android Studio 3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

I've tried all the ways found on StackOverflow and still facing the issue.

I've created a demo Android project with native support, added a library to it and moved all native code into the library.

Now I'm unable to stop on breakpoints in native code, native debugger became active only after a SEGFAULT crash.

I've added `defaultPublishConfig "debug"` into mylibrary `build.gradle` and `debuggable true` to app `build.fradle`. There was enough for native debugging earlier. But it is not working since Android Studio upgrade.

Here are the full `build.gradle` files

**app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.raistlin.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':mylibrary')

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**mylibrary**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        defaultPublishConfig "debug"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang"
                cppFlags "-fexceptions", "-std=c++11", "-DJSONCPP_NO_LOCALE_SUPPORT"
                version "3.10.2"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is, your library use native and is implemented in the app as project, so your app gradle should also be able to use native. Is this in the range of solutions you have try?

Comment: @cutiko No. How can I tell gradle that my app is also native?

Comment: The same way you did with the module https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code?

Comment: @cutiko yes, I can move `externalNativeBuild` sections from library to app, but that's not a solution I want. In previous versions of Android Studio I was able to debug my library with the `build.gradle` files from the question. Now this doesn't work.

Comment: i had this issue once a long time ago. but it happened only one device so I used another and it worked

Comment: It seems I have miss explained myself, I think you have to have the native support in both modules, app and the library module. The library module use native code and the app module implement the library module, so the app module has to be able to support native code as well, otherwise, the implementation won't work because it can be valid for the app module. It is a hypothesis, have you try it?

Comment: @pouya I have several devices. Native debug is really don't work on some of them. But I'm testing this on devices, where I'm abte to debug native applications without libraries. The problem comes once I pass the native code to a library.

Comment: @cutiko I tried to move `externalNativeBuild` sections to app mobule. That works. But in that case the app module compiles native code, but the library uses it. There is no direct native calls in app source code, only in library. That's why it is more logical to have the native support only in library, in my opinion. Not to compile the native code in app, but use in library. Maybe I didn't understand you correctly..

Comment: I think I failed to explain myself again, my idea is you to try not moving the support from one module to another, make both modules have the native support. The native support should be in both gradles. Think it this way: What would you do if you need to add a native library to the app module? You would native support right? In this case your module is the native library. Both modules have to be configured to use native.

Comment: @cutiko Okay. So what I need to write in my app's `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, check debug variant is selected for library.

As your build.gradle has a setting, `path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"`, it won't build I think. So set `targets`, rebuild and check again.

If breakpoints doesn't work after build, old garbage may be left in the build cache and causes problems. Open project directory in explorer and delete build cache (.externalNativeBuild folder) manually and build the project again. I also delete build folder, as it contains .so files in intermediate directory, but it's optional.

Android Studio does not clean libraries in the test device. They are overwritten basically, but clear them manually depending on needs. Files are in /data/app/(package name)/lib/(cpu arch.)/.
NB: Synchronize menu of device file explorer does not synchronize properly under lib or (cpu arch.) directory. To synchronize, select /data or /data/app and choose Synchronize.

NB.1 If `targets` is omitted, Android Studio seems to build no targets. The built output is in (project)/app/build/intermediates/cmake/(flavor)/obj/(cpu architecture). If it seems to work without any targets, check files on device. They confuse test results.

NB.2 `debuggable true` is for release build to enable debugging. No need to set it for debug build, as debuggable flag is set as default.

NB.3 Seems version dependent but Gradle in Android Studio does not clean .externalNativeBuild tree properly even if clean or rebuild is called, and confuses native code build configs. It was around AS3.0, as I remember.

NB.4 My environment is

- Android Stuidio 3.2.1
- classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
- gradle-4.7-all
- CMake: default(3.6.4111459)

I know there are newer versions for Android Studio, Gradle and CMake but they are buggy, so I chose current environment. As far as I've experienced, Android Studio 3.3, gradle:3.3.0, gradle-4.10.1-all have severe bug in VCS(git). Wrong file contents are shown in editor and build fails, sometimes. Setting CMake version to 3.10.x (3.10.2 for me) also seems buggy.

Here's a copy from my project as a sample, partially modified from original one but may work.
I've checked breakpoints in a library work in Android Studio 3.2.1.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static"
                targets "sample"
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Update
[targets](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeCmakeOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeCmakeOptions:targets) is mentioned here [Guide - Link Gradle to your native library - Specify optional configurations](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#pass-args-flags).

Comment: Wow! The `target` option did the trick! I didn't know about it. Maybe you should add a link to the sources to help more people in the future.

Comment: Wow! Deleting the .externalNativeBuild (.cxx for AS 3.6) works for me!